# Is it posible to install debian as host and windows as guest and use nvidia drivers in windows "normally"?

Tags: windows-7, linux, debian, virtual-machine, vmware

i´m new in linux, but i started using debian in  vmware. Now i have windows 7, and debian as a virtual machine.
But I really liked that i can personalize a lot debian, so I decided to use definetly.
So my doubt is: Is it posible to install debian as host and windows 7 as guest in vmware and use windows "normally" ?
I mean, for example, I play some games in steam sometimes, and in windows it´s ok, but if i play games in windows as guest in vmware inside debian, can I run it witout problems? Now I use debian as guest with the noveaua driver(i was searching a few about that)
I ask that if someone already did that, I had some problems before to use my graphic card, nvidia 210, in windows 7 as host and windows 8 as guest. 
If someone can tell me his experience it would be excellent. I need help in that.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The video adapter in VMware guest OS is not nVidia, it's VMware SVGA II, so you can't install/use nVidia drivers inside guest OS (Windows).

For the question about steam, maybe you can try Steam for Linux. I can play Counter-Strike game in Fedora (although it's not as well as playing in Windows).
[image: playing counter-strike in fedora linux OS]

Comment: I will try steam for linux, I play sometimes Left 4 Dead, and in the steam page i don´t see that it´s available for linux, I don´t know how it will work in windows as guest, would it run without problems?

Comment: Left 4 Dead is available in linux: http://www.softpedia.com/reviews/games/linux/Left-4-Dead-2-for-Linux-Review-364144.shtml . I never tried playing 3D game in guest OS, because each time I start a guest OS, VMware Player will give a note: hardware graphic acceleration is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Bridging a video adapter would be awesome I wonder if it's possible with some other open-source virtualisation software if not with VirtualBox.

I'd like to setup a workstation that requires a Windows-only software to run, but I'd also want to be able  to use that machines CPU and storage for other tasks when it's not needed fro the main one.